How to validate Jira webhook event with symmetric key using java
I am trying to validate whether an event received on my end from Jira webhook is valid and safe to use. I am using Java code and trying to validate but it's failing with the message

JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

Step 1: I created a webhook for the Jira API so that when I delete a comment, I should get a notification event.
Used API is: https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira//rest/api/2/webhook
with secret key "secret": "MySecretKey"
Webhook was created successfully and I am able to get the event at my webhook url.
In the header section, I am getting Authorization field which is containing a JWT token.
I am using the below Java code to validate the JWT:
public static boolean validateJiraJWT(String jwtToken, String secretKey) {
    try {           
        Jws<Claims> jws = Jwts.parser()
                //.setSigningKey(jiraPublicKey).build()
        .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKey.getBytes())).build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken);
       
        Claims claims = jws.getBody();
        if (claims.getExpiration().before(new Date())) {
            System.out.println("JWT token has expired.");
            return false;
        }           
        String issuer = claims.getIssuer();
        if (!"jira".equals(issuer)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid issuer.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // JWT token validation failed
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

Now it's failing with said message.
Am I missing something?

As per this page, validation of jwt token in header.authorization is not supported.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Marketplace-Apps-Integrations/JIRA-Automation-Webhooks-Action-JWT-Authentication/qaq-p/732041
Is it correct?
How I can validate my received webhook event that its coming from a valid source?

Its documented that if you have created a subscription for Jira webhook using v2 version of rest api url (https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira//rest/api/2/webhook)then to authenticate received webhook event you will need your user's client secret.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/#registering-a-webhook-using-the-rest-api--for-connect-and-oauth-2-0-apps-
I used below java code snippet to validate:
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

class Main{
    public boolean verify(String jwtToken, String clientSecret){
        claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(clientSecret.getBytes())
                .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
                .getBody();
    }
}

